# Changing the color of SVG Icon on hover

Tags: html, css, svg, hover

I have been trying to change the color of my SVG icons on hover. My SVG icons consist of different shapes like circle, rect, polygon, path, etc.

here is my HTML for SVG:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" class="icon flag-icon1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="64px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 64 54" enable-background="new 0 0 64 54" xml:space="preserve">
  <rect x="0.1" y="0" display="none" fill="#FFFFFF" width="63.9" height="54"></rect>
  <g>
    <g>
      <polygon fill="#010101" points="37,21.6 30.2,28.5 26.8,25 24.9,26.9 30.4,32.4 39.2,23.8       "></polygon>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g>
    <g>
      <path fill="#010101" d="M32,13c-7.7,0-14,6.3-14,14c0,7.7,6.3,14,14,14s14-6.3,14-14C46,19.3,39.8,13,32,13z M32,38.5                          c-6.3,0-11.5-5.1-11.5-11.5c0-6.3,5.1-11.5,11.5-11.5c6.3,0,11.5,5.1,11.5,11.5C43.5,33.3,38.4,38.5,32,38.5z"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

This is the first SVG. Please suggest some way to change its colour to `#ff721f` on hover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach would be to modify your `SVG` structure a little. Wrap the SVG shapes in a `g` element with attribute `fill="currentColor"` and remove `fill` attribute from individual elements. This way you can define / change SVG's color using CSS `color` property:

```css
.flag-icon1 { color: #010101; }

.flag-icon1:hover { color: #ff721f; }
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" class="icon flag-icon1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="64px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 64 54" enable-background="new 0 0 64 54" xml:space="preserve">
  <g fill="currentColor">
    <polygon points="37,21.6 30.2,28.5 26.8,25 24.9,26.9 30.4,32.4 39.2,23.8" />
    <path d="M32,13c-7.7,0-14,6.3-14,14c0,7.7,6.3,14,14,14s14-6.3,14-14C46,19.3,39.8,13,32,13z M32,38.5 c-6.3,0-11.5-5.1-11.5-11.5c0-6.3,5.1-11.5,11.5-11.5c6.3,0,11.5,5.1,11.5,11.5C43.5,33.3,38.4,38.5,32,38.5z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Alternatively, you can use `fill` property to override colours for hover state:

```css
.flag-icon1:hover * {
  fill: #ff721f;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" class="icon flag-icon1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="64px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 64 54" enable-background="new 0 0 64 54" xml:space="preserve">
  <g>
    <polygon fill="#010101" points="37,21.6 30.2,28.5 26.8,25 24.9,26.9 30.4,32.4 39.2,23.8" />
  </g>
  <g>
    <path fill="#010101" d="M32,13c-7.7,0-14,6.3-14,14c0,7.7,6.3,14,14,14s14-6.3,14-14C46,19.3,39.8,13,32,13z M32,38.5 c-6.3,0-11.5-5.1-11.5-11.5c0-6.3,5.1-11.5,11.5-11.5c6.3,0,11.5,5.1,11.5,11.5C43.5,33.3,38.4,38.5,32,38.5z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```